# Invalid JSON data $.get() method - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need help guys.

I am trying to fetch data from the server which is returning JSON data but I am getting the following error message (in Chrome 52).

It seems like the JSON data that is returned is invalid or its not in the expected format.

**ncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

My server is returning data in the following JSON format

```
"[{\"ActionCardId\":1,\"ActionCardNumber\":\"279877\",\"AccountNo\":\"2202322179\",\"ClientName\":null,\"CellNumber\":\"0787596971\",\"TenantName\":null,\"TenantCellNumber\":null,\"AddressStandNo\":null,\"AddressStreet\":\"43 DELMAS AVENUE\",\"AddressSuburb\":\"BOKSBURG\",\"AddressCity\":null,\"AddressPortion\":null,\"AddressEarthNo\":null,\"AddressPremise\":null,\"AddressGISKEY\":null,\"AmountDueTotal\":4080.0,\"AmountDue30Day\":null,\"AmountDueCurrent\":null,\"AmountDue60Day\":null,\"ServiceLevy\":null,\"MeterNumberWater\":null,\"MeterNumberElectricity\":\"M22541\",\"MeterNumberElectricity2\":null,\"MeterNumberElectricity3\":null,\"MeterNumberPrePaid\":null,\"IsPrinted\":true,\"IsResidential\":null,\"ActionSuccessful\":false,\"ActionCardDate\":\"2016-08-20T00:00:00\",\"Remarks\":null,\"UnSuccessfulReason\":null,\"CaptureContractorId\":null,\"AddressCombo\":\", 43 DELMAS AVENUE, BOKSBURG, , \",\"BillCycleName\":\"120\",\"ServiceIndicator\":null,\"WaterReading\":null,\"WaterReadingDate\":null,\"ElectricityReading\":null,\"ElectricityReadingDate\":null,\"Unit\":null,\"ActionCardTypeId\":2,\"ContractorId\":1,\"ActionCardStatusId\":1,\"UnSuccessfulActionReasonId\":null,\"TechnicianId\":1,\"AccountInfoId\":null,\"ServiceDeliveryCentreId\":4,\"BillCycleId\":2,\"ActionCardType\":{\"ActionCardTypeId\":2,\"Active\":null,\"CreatedByOnlineUserId\":null,\"DateCreated\":null,\"DateModified\":null,\"Deleted\":null,\"Description\":\"Electricity Disconnection\",\"ModifiedByOnlineUserId\":null,\"Name\":\"ED\",\"CreatedByUser\":null,\"ModifiedByUser\":null},\"Contractor\":null,\"ActionCardStatus\":null,\"UnSuccessfulActionReason\":null,\"Technician\":null,\"AccountInfo\":null,\"ServiceDeliveryCentre\":null,\"BillCycle\":null,\"ActionName\":\"ED\",\"DateCreated\":\"2016-07-06T00:00:00\",\"DateModified\":\"2016-08-13T10:24:17.5833635\",\"CreatedByOnlineUserId\":null,\"ModifiedByOnlineUserId\":\"fa93e65d-e4a7-4a0c-91c6-4561e2612f9c\",\"CreatedByUser\":null,\"ModifiedByUser\":null}]"
```

I am using Javascript in my client side

```
$("#importDailyJobs").click(function () {

        var technicianId = 1;

        var serverUrl = "http://localhost:35825/Mobile/ImportDailyReadings"

        $.get(serverUrl, { TechnicianId: technicianId }, function (data, status) {

            alert("Success");
            console.log(data);


        }, "jsonp");

    });
```

I using **jsonp** because I am using cross domain to get the data.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` means there's a `<` in the response data. Check the network tab of your browser for the actual response.

Comment: Most commonly - you probably actually got sent an error response in html/xml format.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are encountering an error on that URL and the response is enclosed inside an `html` tag  `<>`.

As suggested by "Jason P" you should check the actual response in the "raw" format. If you are on Google Chrome, you can press F12, then navigate to "Network" Tab, and then select "XHR" after which you should trigger the respective event by clicking on `#importDailyJobs`. You should see the `Ajax  Request`, on clicking of which you shall be able to view the details for that request, like `Headers`, `Preview`, **`Response`** etc.

You can view the raw data inside the `Response` tab.

Also on a side note, just wrap the string in single quotes when you have double quotes inside it, and if you have both then wrap the string in the one which is least used, to prevent lots of `escaping` as can be seen in your sample response.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Here is the **Response**...Unfortunately I cannot post here...its too long. I will try to see whats wrong with it

Comment: @Linda Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @JasonP thank you, I have edited my question with the Json results from the browser. The Json data seems to be fine, but its not running my function (code inside the function). Do you perhaps know why?

Answer (score 0):

Your returned data is not a JSON. It's a string. You explicitly expect JSON via the `jsonp` argument, and you return a string, hence the error.

Comment: JSON *is* a string. If it's not a string, it's not JSON.

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation. JSON is an object. It can be stringified using `JSON.stringify()` and parsed using `JSON.parse()`, but an object is not a string.

Comment: No. The result of `JSON.stringify()` is a string in JSON format. The result of `JSON.parse()` is a javascript object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation or http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Okay so go to jsonlint.com, validate `{"key":"val"}`, and then come again and say "JSON is a string, if it's not a string, it's not JSON". Apparently you don't know what Json is.

Comment: Sure, neither do the people in the links I posted either, apparently.

Comment: I've been a web developer for many years, I'm now MEAN stack developer, I've built countless websites with jQuery, Angular and React, and never, ever have I sent a string as a JSON. And neither has any of my colleagues present here. Never used stringify or parse, always iterated pure JSON from the server. Well, thank you for redefining all I thought I knew.

Comment: Not to spoil that cute little thing that you guyz got there going, Just wanted to say that JSON is not an object or a string its a *notation*, a *format*  that lays the ground rules, which in turn are supposed to help in exchange of data between apps. The exchange is supposed to happen in plain text/string format. Whether to send a correct JSON or an Incorrect one is totally the sender's call, Likewise how to interpret it is totally the receiver's call. Btw, please carry on :)

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib, Yes, it is a notation for representing serialized data *as a string*

Comment: We're not talking about how servers exchange data. In that case, json is a chain of binary numbers or electric impulses. Is "12345" a valid json? Yes. Is `{"key":"val"}` a valid json? Yes. `typeof {"key":"val"} === 'object'`. Hence the statement "if it's not a string it's not json" is wrong, end of story.

Comment: @JeremyThille If you are doing `{"key":"val"} === 'object'` then you are executing javascript code, and in that case, `{"key":"val"}` is a javascript object, not json. json is like xml, it's a way of serializing data. But you don't say you have an xml object, you have an xml-formatted string or text. Just because a json-formatted string looks like the syntax you use to define a javascript object in javascript does not mean that the two are the same thing.

Comment: I think the [ECMA-404 Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) can shed some light on this argument. According to the standard, _"JSON is a text format that facilitates structured data interchange between all programming languages."_ Additionally, _"Programming languages vary widely on whether they support objects, and if so, what characteristics and
constraints the objects offer....Most
programming languages will have some feature for representing such collections, which can go by names like
record, struct, dict, map, hash, or object."_

Comment: So in conclusion, JSON is passed between systems as a serialized string. Whether that system keeps the data as a string or parses it to an object, map, struct, associative array, etc. is entirely dependent on the programming language's interpretation and implementation of the JSON spec. As the standard notes: _"It [JSON based on ECMA Language Specification 3rd edition] does not attempt to impose ECMAScript’s internal data
representations on other programming languages. Instead, it shares a small subset of ECMAScript’s textual
representations with all other programming languages."_

Comment: @War10ck thank you for the lesson and information sharing.

Comment: Does anyone know why my code inside the function does not get executed? `function (data, status) { console.log(data); alert("Success");}`